# How to use React Select if the object properties's are not value and label?

Tags: javascript

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';

let items = [
    {
        item: 1,
        name: "tv"
    },
    {
        item: 2,
        name: "PC"
    }
]

const Home = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(6)

    const handleChange = obj => {
        setSelectedValue(obj.item)
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>Home page</div>

            <p>Test React Select...</p>
            <Select
                value={items.find(x => x.item === selectedValue)}
                options={items}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />

            <p>selected Value:...</p>
            {selectedValue}

        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: The easiest is to `.map` the objects to a form understood by react-select.

Comment: ^ the only way I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the mapped array to "options" property:

```
options={items.map(({item, name}) => ({value: name, label: item}))}
```